# Jquery code not working in Firefox simple click events

Tags: jquery, firefox

Code works in IE and Chrome, not Firefox. No error messagein Firebug, just page reload. And the gallery code and the fadeIn at the beginning work as well, just the subsequent click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.gallery').slick({
        adaptiveHeight:true,
        dots:true,
        arrows:true,
        autoplay:true,
        infinite:true,
});
$("h1").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $("h2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $("h3").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
$("#about").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#aboutContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
});
```

Is it to do with passing the `$('#aboutContainer).offset.top`?

Comment: try putting the $("#about").click(function() event in document.ready

Comment: why did you choose to use: event.preventDefault()

Comment: It is in document.ready, I just didn't show the end of the page.

Comment: without event.preventDefault, the page simply reloads when the element is clicked.

Comment: And let me be clear again, this is working fine in Chrome and IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `event` variable is not being defined. You need to specify it as a closure argument:

```
$("#about").click(function(event) { // <<--- THIS
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#aboutContainer").offset().top
        }, 1000);
});
```

### Edit:

Another thing, you didn't say if you are executing this on page load complete or not. The `#about` element might not be available at the time of execution.

Comment: Didn't help. And the function is within document.ready so I believe that #about is available.

Comment: @bamabacho This is your issue, not explecitely passing `event` as handler function parameter (`function(event)`). FF uses different event model, not using global window event.